# regex for optional group

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'd like to parse the following sample string

```
foo :6
```

into two groups: Text and Number. The number group should be populated only if the character ":" precedes the number itself.

so:

```
foo 6 -> Text = "foo 6"
foo :6 -> Text = "foo", Number = "6"
```

The best I could come up with so far is

```
(?<Text>.+)(?=:(?<Number>\d+)h?)?
```

but that doesn't work because the first group greedily expands to the whole string.

Any suggestions?

Comment: (?<Text>.+?)(?=:(?<Number>\d+)h?)?

Comment: why not just use split?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You don't need any seperate function for stripping the trailing whitespaces**

The below regex would capture all the characters into the named group `Text` except `:\d+`(ie; `:` followed by one or more numbers). If it finds a colon followed by numbers, then it starts capturing the number into the named group `Number`

```
^(?<Text>(?:(?!:\d+).)+(?=$|\s+:(?<Number>\d+)$))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cQ1tQ4/10)

```
String input = "foo 6";
String input1 = "foo :6";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^(?<Text>(?:(?!:\d+).)+(?=$|\s+:(?<Number>\d+)$))");

foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
{
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["Text"].Value);
}
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input1))
{
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["Text"].Value);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["Number"].Value);
}
```

Output:

```
foo 6
foo
6
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/S7dUW2)

Comment: Seems like the best match for what I want to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you *really* want to use a regex you can write quite a simple one, without lookarounds:

```
(?<Text>[^:]+):?(?<Number>\d*)
```

In my opinion, regexes should be as simple as possible; if you do not want spaces around the `Text` group I suggest you use `match.Groups["Text"].Value.Strip()`.

Note that if you are parsing a multiline string this pattern will not work because, as @OscarHermosilla mentioned below, `[?:]+` will also match newlines. The fix is simple though, change it with `[^:\n]`

Comment: @Unihedron I guess it depends on OP's intentions

Comment: See test case: `foo :6 -> Text = "foo", Number = "6"`

Comment: I agree with you regex should be simple and this will do the job. But it should be applied individually to every string to be parsed. But it won't work in a text with several lines becuase [^:]+ will also match new-line.

Comment: @OscarHermosilla you are correct, indeed, I posted this because the question seems to suggest that individual strings will be used. I will add this to my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can repeat the group name text with an alternation. This way:

```
(?<Text>.+)\s+:(?<Number>\d)|(?<Text>.+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fG0vL5/3)

Based on the idea behind this post: [Regex Pattern to Match, Excluding when... / Except between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/regex-pattern-to-match-excluding-when-except-between)

Comment: It could be easily fixed if it is needed

Comment: For example: `(?<Text>.+)\s+:(?<Number>\d)|(?<Text>.+)`

Comment: @Unihedron Not really, at least I tried it and it doesn't seem to work http://regex101.com/r/vJ4hI8/1

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use split instead of regex:

```
"foo :6".Split(':');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like:

```
(\D+)(?:\:(\d+))
```

or do a `Regex.Split` using this pattern:

```
(\s*\:\s*)
```